# Multiple react apps on multiple domains. How to hide port in url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, .htaccess, https

I got 2 domains **"abc.com"** and **"def.com"**. On ports **443** and **3001** I got **React apps**. Both domains go to same server.

I would like htaccess to run react app from port 3001 ( without showing port number ) when user try to access "def.com" and open deafult 443 port when user try to access "abc.com" ( simulate that both domains run on 443 )

After messing with .htaccess, I managed to get this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}:3001

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^def\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Second site run on default ports ( 80 and 443 ) where first run on 3001. Is there any "easy" way to hide port in url other than messing with javascript on each request?

In my perfect world, both would run on 443 and .htaccess would manage domains but since I don't know any better way for that, thats how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `port-based virtual hosting` using `Apache Web Server`. There could be other ways too, but you can give it a try.

There could be multiple steps to follow, but they are quite easy and simple. I'm not sure which OS or hosting environment you are using though you should [check](https://geekflare.com/multiple-domains-on-one-server-with-apache-nginx/) this.

Comment: I saw that link before but code inside of it makes 2 different folders for domains to use. Problem is that react app work on port so I need to somehow force another port to be used. Take for example my code. It redirect domain 2 to port 3001.
I could manually "def.com:3001" but this code just redirect users. Its working but I would like to just hide that port number. I can do it ofc using javascript but I would need to rewrite whole router for that and it will take time and unnecessary code